# ASP.NET Core - How to check if a field exists from a given third party API before sending Email

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

In my ASP.NET Core-6 Web API, I am given a third party API to consume and then return the account details. I am using HttpClient.

api:

```
https://api.thirdpartycompany.com:2233/UserAccount/api/AccountDetail?accountNumber=
```

In appsettings.json I have:

```
"Endpoints": {
  "customerUrl": "https://api.thirdpartycompany.com:2233/UserAccount/api/AccountDetail?accountNumber="
}
```

DTO:

```
public class GetCustomerDetailDto
{
    public class CustomerDetail
    {
        public string AccountNumber { get; set; }
        public string Fullname { get; set; }
        public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Then I have this Data Util:

```
public class DataUtil : IDataUtil
{
    private readonly IConfiguration _config;
    private readonly ILogger<DataUtil> _logger;
    private readonly HttpClient _myClient;
    public DataUtil
        (
        IConfiguration config,
        ILogger<DataUtil> logger, 
        HttpClient myClient
        )
    {
        _config = config;
        _logger = logger;
        _myClient = myClient;
    }
    public CustomerDetail GetCustomerDetail(string accountNumber)
    {
        var responseResults = new CustomerDetail();
        try
        {
            string custAccountNoUrl = _config.GetSection("Endpoints").GetValue<string>("customerUrl") + accountNumber;
            _myClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            _myClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            HttpResponseMessage response = _myClient.GetAsync(custAccountNoUrl).Result;
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var stringResult = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                responseResults = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CustomerDetail>(stringResult);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogError($"An Error occured " + ex.ToString());
        }
        return responseResults;
    }
}
```

Then this is the implementation:

```
public async Task<Response<string>> CreateCustomerDetailAsync(CreateDto requestDto)
{
    var response = new Response<string>();
    var accDetail = _dataAccess.GetCustomerDetail(requestDto.DrAccountNumber);
    if (accDetail.EmailAddress != null)
    {
       var accountName = accDetail.Fullname;
       var emailAddress = accDetail.EmailAddress.ToLower();
       var mailBody = await EmailBodyBuilder.GetCustomerEmailBody(accountName, emailTempPath: "wwwroot/files/Html/CustomerEmail.html");
       var mailRequest = new MailRequest()
       {
          Subject = "Customer Notification",
          Body = mailBody,
          ToEmail = emailAddress
       };
       bool emailResult = await _mailService.SendEmailAsync(mailRequest);
       if (emailResult)
       {
           response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK;
           response.Successful = true;
           response.Message = "Successful!";
           return response;
       }
    }
}
```

From the third-party API given, there are moments when the customer does not have email address, then the EmailAddress field will not even appear at all from the response.

So that made me to get error here:

```
bool emailResult = await _mailService.SendEmailAsync(mailRequest);
```

I tried

> if (accDetail.EmailAddress != null)

but it's not solving the problem.

Making use of

```
public async Task<Response<string>> CreateCustomerDetailAsync(CreateDto requestDto)
```

How do I make the application not to send email at all whenever EmailAddress field does not exist or it's null?

Comment: `but it's not solving the problem.` what does it mean? Does it throw exception? what exception? Did you try `!string.IsNullOrEmpty(accDetail.EmailAddress)` ?

Comment: @Chetan - As I stated, there are times EmailAddress field is not even present in the third-party api response at all. Not just that it's null or empty

Comment: If the field is not there in the response JSON, when you deserialize it to your class object, the respective property should have default value (which should be null for the string property). Can you share what error you are getting when the field is missing in the JSON? `!string.IsNullOrEmpty(accDetail.EmailAddress)` did this work for you?

Comment: You might also want to log the value of response JSON and `accDetail.EmailAddress` to see what value you are getting from the API and how it is converted to class object. It will help you nail down the issue which causing this problem.

Comment: `EmailAddress field is not even present in the third-party api response at all`, then after `var stringResult = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;`, I think you can also check if there's `EmailAddress` contained in the string. By the way, I remembered that I saw somewhere which mentioned don't use `.Result` but use `await` instead.